# run M-file on multiple images and write output images

Tags: matlab

I have written a M-file. I'd like to run this M-file on multiple images and then write output .tif images by naming separately. Is there easy way to do this?

Thank all

Comment: Yes. [Write a function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html).

Comment: Could you give an idea of how the input files are stored, how is the processing like and how you want the output?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new in matlab. I can do to call the function on command line to run on single images one by one. I know matlab is so flexible to run the function on multiple images at the same time. But I don't know the way to do this.Could you give me some idea?

Comment: To run program file, 2 set of monthly images 2006 to 2009 are used as inputs to calculate these functions. These 2 set of images are stored in 2 different folders. For ex; 'TMP' folder contains the files named tmp_2006_4.tif, tmp_2006_5.tif...tmp_2009_10, 'rnf'folder contains the files rnf_2006_4, rnf_2006_5...rnf_2009_10. When I call the program file on command line, I enter input images one by one. I don't want this. I want to run the program on all monthly images from 2006-2009 as a single command or single program file. The output I want should be clc_2006_4, clc_2006_5...clc_2009_10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to write a function:

```
function img( inputName, outputName )

    if ~iscell(inputName)
         img( {inputName}, {outputName} ); 
            return; 
    end   

    for ii = 1:numel(inputName)

        im = imread(inputName{ii});

        ...

        [do operations on im]

        ...

        imwrite(im, outputName{ii}, 'tiff');

    end

end
```

which you can call from a script, class, function or command window like so:

```
img(...
    {'file1.bmp', 'file2.bmp', ...},...
    {'file1.tif', 'file2.tif', ...}...
);
```

You can get input filenames like so:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
   {'*.bmp','bitmap-files (*.bmp)'; ...
    '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
    'Pick a file', ...
    'MultiSelect', 'on');
```

so you can use

```
if filename ~= 0
    img(...
        [char(pathname) char(filename)],
        {'file1.tif', 'file2.tif', ...}...
    );
else
    error('No file selected.');
end
```

which already indicates you can better recycle the input filenames:

```
function img( fileNames )

    ... % function's mostly the same, except: 

    [pth,fname] = fileparts(fileNames{ii});

    imwrite(im, [pth filesep fname '.tif'], 'tiff');

end
```

Or, for added convenience when using `uigetfile`,

```
if filename ~= 0
    img(pathname, filename);

else
    error('No file selected.');
end
```

with

```
function img( pathnames, filenames)

    if ~iscell(pathnames)
         img( {pathnames}, {filenames} ); 
            return; 
    end   

    for ii = 1:numel(pathnames)

        im = imread([pathnames{ii} filenames{ii}]);

        ...

        [do operations on im]

        ...

        [~,basename] = fileparts(filenames{ii});
        imwrite(im, [basename '.tif'], 'tiff');

    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you Rody, I have 2 questions. 1. How to enter second set of input data. Do I need to enter this code 2 times within a program file? After entering both time series images 2. how can I tell to matlab to run this programm on the images of the same month and year. for ex; First time the program run on April images in 2006. (tmp_2006_4 and rnf_2006_4), then output clc_2006_4, second time for next month's images (tmp_2006_5 and rnf_2006_5)...etc